# Is PGP suitable for encrypting webservices?

Tags: pgp, web-service, confidentiality

I would like to know if I can use of PGP to ensure SOAP webservices confidentiality?
I don't want use SSL, it's kind of slow mechanism to make a tunnel for high throughput data transaction. 
I though cypher data using a symmetric key, the key will be encrypted to by a asymmetric public key. And push the message in the network, just the intended receiver can read it. 
Is it a good fair pattern for web services?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Remember the old advice when it comes to security: "Don't roll your own!"

Answer (score 2):

SSL will be faster than SOAP+PGP.  Cryptographically, both SSL and PGP are hybrid systems which use public key cryptography to protect symmetric session keys.  In practice, SSL has been tuned on the client and server side to do what it's doing quickly, PGP hasn't been optimized for this case.  And you'll have to figure out your key distribution and trust mechanism if you roll your own PGP method.

Doing your own encryption will have the advantages of protecting it from the usual cases - MITM proxies, accelerator decryption.

Without knowing more about your app, it's hard to say, but in most cases, it's not worth it to go your own way.  SSL provides pretty darn good security for the average application.

Comment: I am just afraid of the tunneling/bidirection effort in SSL.

Comment: And would like make perplex a hacker if he succeed breaking our security network. Even he get access to the message, he can't be sure decyphing it correctly, 'cause in all cases the webservice will output a response tuple : cypher and the encrypted session key or a misleading key whether he is recognized in our identity/user manager.

Comment: I'm beginning to feel two or more of us don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

PGP/GPG is generally not used for web services.  It relies on anyone communicating to have the public key of who they're communicating with.  In web services this generally isn't guaranteed.  So depending on the type of service you're providing this might not be ideal.

If you're trying to only provide services to a select group of people then you'd have to make sure you have a keyserver set up, all users would have to generate/have PGP/GPG keys, all users would have to upload those keys to the keyserver, and your application would have to provide means to configure which keyserver to use.

In my opinion it's not worth the overhead to use PGP/GPG instead of SSL/TLS.  Any kind of slowness you might think SSL/TLS has is made up with ease of use and accessibility.  And in all honesty, it's really not slow.  There's a reason why most applications use it for web-based security.

Straight from the [SOAP Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Processing_model)

> SOAP may also be used over HTTPS (which is the same protocol as HTTP at the application level, but uses an encrypted transport protocol underneath) with either simple or mutual authentication; this is the advocated WS-I method to provide web service security as stated in the WS-I Basic Profile 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is already included in most libraries nativelly, so the difference between a plain text webservice and the SSL version is negligible in terms of development on both sides.
If the client makes use of persistent connections or reuses the SSL session, the negotiation between client and server is even lighter and faster.
The authentication proccess is easier by using a well-known Certificate Authority, so there is no need to exchange keys.
Also, there are SSL-accelerators which use hardware specific components to reduce CPU load.